# Web api routing - cannot access default route?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I would like the following routes in my web api:

/api/week/2013/08/29 <-- this is a specific week

/api/week/ <-- this is the last week

{and some default route to other api-controllers}

I've implemented a Get function which correctly retrieves the information, but I have a problem with the routing.

I have declared the following:

```
   config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
         name: "WeekRoute",
         routeTemplate: "api/week/{year}/{month}/{day}",
         defaults: new { controller = "Week" },
         constraints: new { year = @"\d{1,4}", month = @"[1-9]|1[0-2]", day = @"[0-9]|[0-2][0-9]|3[0-1]" }
    );

    // I don't think I'd even need this one, but I put it here for specificity
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
         name: "DefaultWeek",
         routeTemplate: "api/week",
         defaults: new { controller = "Week", action="Get" }
    );

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
         name: "ApiDefault",
         routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
         defaults: new { controller = "Week", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
```

My action:

```
[WeekFilter] // This filters out the year/month/day string and creates a DateTime
public IEnumerable<Week> Get(DateTime? week = null){...}
```

I have been trying for a while now, but I can't seem to get the "/api/week/" one to work.. I don't think there is a problem with my action (or the fact that it has an optional parameter), but the routing seems to be wrong, yet I can't figure out why...

Thanks for your help!

EDIT:

The WeekFilter:

```
public class WeekFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        var year = actionContext.ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["year"] as string;
        var month = actionContext.ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["month"] as string;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(year) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(month))
        {
            var day = actionContext.ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["day"] as string;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(day)) 
                day = "1";

            var datum = new DateTime(int.Parse(year), int.Parse(month), int.Parse(day));
            actionContext.ActionArguments["week"] = datum;
        }

        base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);
    }
}
```

The action:

```
[WeekFilter]
public IEnumerable<Week> Get(DateTime? week = null)
{
    return HandlerLocator.GetQueryHandler<IGetWeeksDataHandler>().Execute(week);
}
```

Comment: What kind of error are you getting? Ambiguous match?

Comment: 404 when I try /api/ or /api/week/, /api/week/2013/08/29 gives me the correct result

Comment: Ok, and does your /api/week/2013/08/29 work?

Comment: Yes, it gives me the correct result

Comment: Added the attribute and the action (although that just calls my querycommand)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36461/discussion-between-joel-and-team-joki)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my mistake.

In my global asax, I had:

```
   FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
   RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
   WebApiConfig.RegisterRoutes(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
   BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
```

But apparently the location of the web Api routing matters, I changed it to

```
   WebApiConfig.RegisterRoutes(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
   FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
   RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);       
   BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
```

and now it works!

Answer (score 0):

By changing your `DateTime? week` parameter to have a default value of null both your routes are working:

```
[WeekFilter] 
public IEnumerable<Week> Get(DateTime? week = null)
{
    return null;
}
```

When you call your controller with `api/week`, the week parameter on your action method is `null`. You could change this by modifying your `WeekFilter` to initialize week if year and month are empty.

If you call it with `/api/week/2013/8/13` everything works as expected.